# R: Merge dataframes by nearest datetime

Tags: r, datetime, merge, data.table

I have two dataframes of different lengths: NROW(data) = 20000
NROW(database) = 8000

Both of dataframes have date time values in a format as : YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS which are not  the same in each dataframe

What I want is to merge them by the nearest date-time and keep only the records that exist in database.

I tried the approach posted in another stackexchange post
[R – How to join two data frames by nearest time-date?][1]

based on data.table library. I tried following but without success:

```
require("data.table")
database <- data.table(database)
data <- data.table(data)

setkey( data, "timekey")
setkey( database, "timekeyd")

database <- data[ database, roll = "nearest"]
```

But the merge was almost completely wrong. You can see how the merged was performed in the following table that has only the two keys (timekey and timekeyd)

```
1   2017-11-01 00:00:00 2017-10-31 21:00:00
2   2017-11-01 00:00:00 2017-10-31 22:10:00
3   2017-11-02 19:00:00 2017-11-02 21:00:00
4   2017-11-02 19:00:00 2017-11-02 21:00:00
5   2017-11-03 20:08:00 2017-11-03 22:10:00
6   2017-11-04 19:00:00 2017-11-04 21:00:00
7   2017-11-04 19:00:00 2017-11-04 21:00:00
8   2017-11-05 19:00:00 2017-11-05 21:10:00
9   2017-11-07 18:00:00 2017-11-07 20:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Sotos, that solution provided in that question, does not work in my case

Comment: Are you sure your dates aren't saved as strings? They should be something like `POSIXct`.